# My UV don't match the object's shape

Tags: uv

[image: UV panel is displaying the incorrect representation of my object.]

I have marked the seams on appropriate edges and have unwrapped my object yet i get this on my UV panel. I have tried using the 'Correct aspect' feature however, it comes up with:

[image]

Anyone here who knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can scale to uniform scale by pressing `ctrl + A` in Object mode. Select `apply scale` and unwrap again.

[image]